# Limit question with x and y help?

Tags: limits

Give me a clue how to find the limit as x and y approach zero of $(x^2+y^2)*\sin(1/xy)$...I thought about multiplying up and down with $xy$ but that didn't give me anything....

Comment: Squeezing principle. Sine of anything is bounded.

Comment: @Aaron to prove the limit existence, you should not take a particular case of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: There is the unpleasantness that if for example we travel towards $(0,0)$ on the $x$-axis, our function is not defined.

Comment: When you get an answer that is helpful, you may choose to accept exactly one answer: to accept an answer, click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 
$$|\sin(1/xy)|\leq 1$$
and $$x^2+y^2\to0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$a=\frac{1}{xy}$

$ \ Lim_ {a \to \infty} \sin a=[1,-1]=z$, A real value.

$ \ Lim_ {x,y \to 0} \ (x^2+y^2) \sin a=0.$